# spark sql executes very slow

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### Question resolved. there are huge same key in table_b

I have a sql like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbale_b b ON a.key=b.key
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c c on a.key2=c.key2
```

The query is executed by spark on yarn.

As usual, there is only one record in table_b has the same key in table_a,
the query can be executed very fast and correctly

But if there are some records repeated in table_b, the query will be executed very slow, one of the reduce tasks will have very high

[spark job snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJfah.png)

Comment: And where is the problem? Always remember Spark isn't your typical RDBMS where you can have a large number of joins

Comment: thank you, but there are about 2 billions records int table_a,  this job is about ETL. first, we have load all data to HDFS, then i use spark job to transform these data

Comment: there is a the screenshot of the job: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJfah.png

Comment: Have you tried switching around the join order? so maybe try to join c frist to a and then b ?

Comment: not yet. but i anylized the table_b, and i fund there are repeated records, about 10%, total records are 10 million. I tried to select distinct table_b, then the query can execute success and fast

Comment: so i want to know , why it happens . In fact , left outer join with two or more records in single key is common

Comment: and if next time, ETL job need to left outer join with dataset which has repeated records,  what should i do to use spark-sql

Comment: finally thank you very much , this is my first question ,and you r my first answer ^_^

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had Spark  jobs last up to 4 hours on a hundred node cluster.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but a join is an expensive operation in a distributed environment, you have a reasonable amount of data, there's gonna be a significant shuffle overhead, and with duplicate keys there is a duplication of effort. Given these factors, the processing times look reasonable to me. Probably stating the obvious here but, de-duplicating might be a sensible pre-processing step?

Comment: If only has join(in RDD may be groupByKey etc.) ,shuffle happens. Without duplicate keys , shuffle can be  evenly distributed to each task. But if only has duplicate keys , the huge shuffle will be execute in only one task.  It seems data skew happened. But How and Why?

Comment: 4 hours? the amount of data would be very very huge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly, i found that there are many same key in table_b

the join result is very huge

the same key will be executed in only one task